# Innovative methods for form input on mobile

Tags: forms, mobile, registration, mobile-application, mobile-web

Looking to have a form on mobile for scheduling an appointment (similar to registration form info), run in a webapp.

Are there any better, innovative, more interesting methods to do a form on mobile? Examples?

Comment: Is this question OS-specific, cross-platform, or a webapp? Will this be coded through a custom app, or are you looking for form tools? A bit more detail would be welcome.

Comment: Webapp, not looking for specific tools but rather ways of doing it such as "staged obligation"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a combination of being primarily opinion based and a general search for ideas rather than asking about a specific UX problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be already familiar with it, but staged obligation is one of the best methods for lengthy form inputs.

This might be best exemplified in online store checkouts. Instead of inputting their shipping/billing address, applicable discounts, and payment info all in to one lengthy form, it is broken down into steps. This is also seen in surveys, where questions are grouped into different pages, so potential respondents aren't scared off when they see the amount of questions being asked.

Applying this to other forms will keep the user interested. You will see some users bail when they see the next page, but most will be in the mindset of, "I've already filled out the last page, and there's only a few more boxes. I'll keep going." A progress indicator is helpful for users to understand what they're getting into, but it may scare away some.

Although you haven't shared details on what goes into scheduling an appointment for your application, I could easily convert the process into steps:

- Information about you
- Who you need to see and why
- Pick a date and time
- Confirm and make appointment

And assuming the user wants to schedule the appointment (as opposed to say, filling out a survey), I could see this being very effective.

However, because the form in question would be on mobile and is subject to more potential interruptions between steps (network difficulties, data usage, app crashes, etc.), separation by pages might not be effective. Steps could instead be separated on a single page, such as through drop-down views that reveal themselves as the user completes the previous step.