# Forms? One question at a time or the whole form on one page?

Tags: forms, user-expectation

I am trying to create a command line interface for my website, I need to decide whether I should ask user to enter his details in a command line (Which makes it one field at a time) or should I pop up a normal form which can show everything at once.

Which is a better approach?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "a command line interface"? Something that runs in a terminal? If so, what do you consider "a normal form" in a terminal?

Comment: When I say a command line interface, imagine it like a terminal running in your browser, telling you to enter your email, your name.

When I say a normal form, it means a normal form as the one you can see on Facebook/Twitter

Comment: OK, so we're talking about a website, not a command line program.

Comment: Yes, a website. An example can be [typeform](http://www.typeform.com/) or [Google form](https://forms.google.com)

Comment: This might help: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/79698/innovative-methods-for-form-input-on-mobile/79700#79700

Comment: Please, provide a mockup with your proposed method, I don't want to answer without knowing if it has the drawbacks that I think it could have.

Comment: So “command line” here means “wizard” or “dialog-based”?

Comment: How many inputs you want the user to fill?

Comment: We can't possibly answer this question given that limited amount of info.

Comment: Asking one question at time is so much better than put in front of users a long page forms. The perception is that the process is less long and quicker,even if there are many questions to ask. The cognitive load to answer one question at time is very low, so it seems quicker. In the agency where I work we used this approach for long forms (like insurance quoting) and the conversion rate is ever higher than traditional forms.

Answer (score 0):

If the site is for developers or those who are familiar with command line, you can use one, but usually not so much people love the restricted feeling of a command line. You can use a form, and chunk it in category(e.g. Personal details, skills, experience, etc.) For pop-up form, I think is not great because is used as a dark pattern, and usually is not thinked for the benefit of the user.

As a UX designer, you are advocating for the user. :)
(And sometimes you are the user).

Comment: "Dark patterns" are elements designed to trick users into performing certain actions or accepting certain terms or conditions. I don't think the way you used it here is correct.

Comment: Can you explain why "pop-up" form (a form in a modal), is a dark pattern and why it doesn't benefit the user?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user to fill one Input at a time then you shouldn't have more than 5 Inputs to fill. **Always show at each input what is the current user location (Progress e.g 80% completed)**

**If you have more than 5 input fields then display the form in an overlay** as users might lose interest in Single Input at a time form method if you have too many fields to fill

One other problem which comes with filling those forms, **how will you handle errors in each field**. If the errors returns after submitting the form, how will you refill the form with the previous data